# Cumulative Additions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add the previous row value to the current row and keep this adding until I reach the total.

I have tried the below query and I have set row number to the rows as per my needs, the additions should take place in the same manner.

```
select * 
from #Finalle 
order by rownum ;
```

Output:

```
Type                    Count_DB    Rownum
------------------------------------------
Within 30 days          399480       1
Within 60 days          30536        2
Within 90 days          10432        3
Within 120 days         11777        4
Greater than 120 days   13091        5
Blank                   29297        6
Total                   494613       7
```

When I try the below query, it works fine until the 6th row, but fails for the last row:

```
select 
    f1.[type],
    (select 
         Sum(f.[Count of ED_DB_category]) as [Cummumative] 
     from 
         #Finalle f 
     where 
         f1.rownum >= f.rownum) 
from 
    #Finalle f1
order by 
    rownum
```

Output:

```
Type                   No column name
--------------------------------------
Within 30 days         399480
Within 60 days         430016
Within 90 days         440448
Within 120 days        452225
Greater than 120 days  465316
Blank                  494613 <---Add only until here
Total                  989226
```

Here the total should return the same value as in the first table.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: As an aside (from a data analyst point of view), `Greater than 120 days` wouldn't be cumulative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may looking for this

```
select f1.[type],
       (select Sum(f.[Count of ED_DB_category])  
               from #Finalle f where f1.rownum >= f.rownum AND 
                f.Type <> 'Total'
       )as [Cummumative]
from #Finalle f1
order by rownum
```

Comment: ohgod!! that was so silly, Thanks a lot :) It Works.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select f1.[type],
       CASE
          WHEN type = 'Total' THEN f1.[Count_DB]
          ELSE SUM(f1.[Count_DB]) OVER (ORDER BY rownum) 
       END      
from #Finalle f1
order by rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use windowed function....
Here's a SWAG but I am not sure of your table structures.....or what to order by

```
SELECT 
  f1.[type], 
  SUM(f.[Count of ED_DB_category]) OVER(ORDER BY f1.[type] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Cummumative]
FROM 
FROM #Finalle f1
WHERE f.Type <> 'Total'
```